# How to evaluate a notebook from the command line?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

How can we evaluate a Mathematica notebook from the command line (i.e. when running the kernel in command line mode)?

Suppose we're working on a remote machine.  I know it is possible to convert the notebook to an m-file, and evaluate that, but I'm curious if it's possible to do this directly using the notebook.

---

This is what I have so far:

First, [we need to start a headless X server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) on the remote Linux machine, so the front end can run there (and open the notebook).  Skip this step if you're working on a local machine.

```
Xvfb :1 &
export DISPLAY=:1
```

After this I started a Mathematica kernel (`math`) and did the following.

It's necessary to use `UsingFrontEnd` because opening notebook requires a front end. test.nb has a single input cell containing `a=1`.

```
In[1]:= nb=UsingFrontEnd@NotebookOpen["test.nb"]

Out[1]= -NotebookObject-
```

After trying to evaluate the notebook, apparently I get a [dialog](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dialog.html), and I need to use `Return[]` to return.  I am not sure why the input line starts counting from 1 again (a new kernel was started by the front end?)  Note that `a` didn't gain a value.

```
In[2]:= UsingFrontEnd@NotebookEvaluate[nb]

 In[1]:= a

 Out[1]= a

 In[2]:= Return[]

Out[2]= a
```

After returning from the dialog, `a` still doesn't have a value.

```
In[3]:= a

Out[3]= a
```

Comment: Looks like we're working in a similar way and are equally lazy!

Comment: +1 I'd love to know this, too! I'd love to evaluate my notebooks on a remote system on our HPC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is on Windows, using Arnouds nice work and just adding plain old MathLink (pretty slow btw ...):

```
link = LinkCreate["8000", LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"];
UsingFrontEnd[
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb_] := Module[{},
 While[ NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb], Pause[.25] ] ];
NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb_]:=Module[{},
 SelectionMove[nb,All,Notebook];
 Or@@Map["Evaluating"/.#&,Developer`CellInformation[nb]]
];
nb = NotebookOpen["G:\\mma\\test.nb"];
SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["Link = LinkConnect[\"8000\", LinkProtocol -> \"TCPIP\"]", "Input"]];
SelectionMove[nb, After, Notebook];
NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["LinkWrite[Link, a]", "Input"]];
SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
SelectionEvaluate[nb];
a = LinkRead[link];
Print["a = ",a];
]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Do we really need `LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"` here or can we use the more efficient default?  (I think by default it uses memory mapped files for interprocess commuincation)

Comment: Probably. At least I cannot get it to work with LinkProtocol -> "SharedMemory"

Comment: BTW: Why do you really need this at all? Is it not easier to save your results by DumpSave or some such?

Comment: Perhaps he develops code on a laptop and wants to run it on remote machines. That is what I do and I find these answers very useful (and using a notebook rather than an m file is, in my case, so I can mix code and typeset discussion).

Answer (score 11):

This is a partial answer to your question. The following code opens a notebook, assigns it a
"Test" kernel, evaluates the notebook in that kernel, waits for the evaluation to finish and
saves the evaluated notebook. It does *not* cause `a` to be defined in the local command line kernel though.

This waits for kernel evaluations to finish in the notebook:

```
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb_] := Module[{},
 While[ NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb], Pause[.25] ] ]
```

This checks if any cell in the notebook is still under evaluation:

```
NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb_]:=Module[{},
 SelectionMove[nb,All,Notebook];
 Or@@Map["Evaluating"/.#&,Developer`CellInformation[nb]]
]
```

This is just a diagnostic message, when you're trying to redefine a kernel like "Test":

```
AddTestEvaluator::exists = "Evaluator `1` is already defined, but has a definition that is `2` and not the expected `3`.";
```

This is code to add an evaluator, like "Test" to the frontend:

```
AddTestEvaluator[evaluator_String] := Module[
 {evaluatornames, testevaluator},
 evaluatornames = EvaluatorNames /. Options[$FrontEnd, EvaluatorNames];
 testevaluator = evaluator -> {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False};
 Which[
  MemberQ[evaluatornames, evaluator -> {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}],
  Null,
  MemberQ[evaluatornames, evaluator -> _],
  Message[AddTestEvaluator::exists,
  evaluator,
  evaluator /. (EvaluatorNames /. Options[$FrontEnd, EvaluatorNames]),
  {"AutoStartOnLaunch" -> False}
 ],
 True,
 AppendTo[evaluatornames, testevaluator];
 SetOptions[$FrontEnd, EvaluatorNames -> evaluatornames]
 ]
]
```

Finally, this is the code to evaluate a notebook under a "Test" kernel and save the evaluated kernel:

```
 UsingFrontEnd[     
  AddTestEvaluator["Test"];
  nb = NotebookOpen["test.nb"];
  SetOptions[nb,Evaluator->"Test"];
  SelectionMove[nb,All,Notebook];
  SelectionEvaluate[nb];
  NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb];
  NotebookSave[nb]
 ]
```

I'm still looking into a solution for your full problem (having `a` defined in the local command
line kernel).

Comment: This is already very useful!  Do you know if there is an *easy* way to transfer definitions associated with a symbol between kernels?  This is exactly what happens during parallel computations, and what `DistributeDefinitions` does.  So I guess this is already implemented.  But are the functions that do this user-accessible?